# Why is my UPDATE query returning fewer results than the equivilent SELECT query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to run an `UPDATE` query in Access 2010 to remove trailing spaces from a field. Before running the full query, I'm writing a test query limited by an ID that returns 1 result, in case anything goes horribly wrong.

The `SELECT` version of the query returns one result, as expected:

```
SELECT dbo_Contact.ContactID, dbo_Contact.Pref
FROM dbo_Contact
WHERE (((dbo_Contact.ContactID)=11906) AND ((dbo_Contact.Pref) Like "% "));
```

However, when I change it to an `UPDATE` query, it says "You are about to update 0 row(s)."

The `UPDATE` query is below:

```
UPDATE dbo_Contact SET dbo_Contact.Pref = Left([Pref],(Len([Pref])-1))
WHERE (((dbo_Contact.ContactID)=11906) AND ((dbo_Contact.Pref) Like "% "));
```

What am I doing wrong? Being that the `WHERE` filter is the same, I'm assuming it's in the expression I'm using as the value to update to. If this is the case, what's wrong with that?

Comment: For the most part, the Access wildcard is *, not %. There are exceptions, but I am not sure if you have such a setup.

Comment: Yep, that solved it. Do you want to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, the Access wildcard is *, not %. There are exceptions, but I am not sure if you have such a setup.